# Array inclusion checking with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, include

I need to check if array

```
a1 = [x, y]
```

is presented in array of arrays like

```
a2 = [ [a, b], [c,d], [e, f] ]
```

with Ruby 1.9.
For example, if `x == c` and `y == d` then function must be `True`.
I'v tried

`a2.includes? a1` and `a1 in a2`
but both doesent work.

Comment: Will `a2.any? { |x| x.eql? a1 }` do?

Comment: yep, i just checked and it works too, alongside with `include?`

Comment: I always keep the documentation for `Array` and `Enumerable` from [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) up in my browser at all times when I am coding. It is an invaluable source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see you used **`includes?`**, which should be [**`include?`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F).

```
a2 = [ [:a, :b], [:c,:d], [:e,:f] ]
a1 = [:a,:b] 
p a2.include? a1 #=>true
```

or you could do so as below:

```
a2 = [ [:a, :b], [:c,:d], [:e,:f] ]
a1 = [:a,:b] 
p a2.one? { |i| i == a1} #=>true
```